# option pricing with limitation on the change of underlying daily changes

Tags: option-pricing

how are we supposed to price an European option given the fact that the daily return of the underlying is limited within -X% to X%?

For example, if X = 5, the price of the underlying cannot go up 8% on any given day.

Comment: I'm not aware of closed form solutions but have you looked binomial trees?

Comment: it occurs to me BT would help. however, determining the probability, up/down size, and etc, in my own opinion, would be too subjective, which makes me critical abt the results of the model. especially under the circumstance of real trading. @BobJansen

Comment: What sort of distribution are you assuming that the returns have?  Truncated normal?  How extreme are the cutoffs $2\sigma$?  $6\sigma$?

Comment: it's absolutely not normal, due to the limits of daily return. i have been thinking a way to get around this for a while, but cannot figure out one.@Degustaf

Comment: Note that +-X% isn't actually symmetric. For example, if a stock went up 5% and then went down 5%, it would be at 99.75% of its original value (1.05*0.95=0.9975). Perhaps limit the log of the price to +-X from the original price? Otherwise, you'll need an asymmetric distribution.

Comment: @Decipher There are techniques to transform any distribution $Y$ into a truncated distribution $Z$ by setting $P(Z < z) = P(Y < Z) / P(-X < Y < X)$ for $-X < Y < X$. But, without some sort of assumptions about the distribution, you won't be able to really say anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

As Black Scholes model, you can assume a two-sided [Truncated Normal Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution#Definition) as riskneutral density $f(x)$ (with $\mu=0,\sigma=T-t$) for the returns and then price the option payoff $H$ as usual by:

$$V_t^H=e^{-r(T-t)}E(H_T|F_t)=e^{-r(T-t)}\int_{-X}^{X}H(S_te^{r(T-t)+\sigma W_{T-t}})f(W_{T-t})dW_{T-t}$$

The integral must likely be calculated numerically. The $\sigma$ parameter must be calibrated from market prices.

Comment: That would of course work but I don't think it models the price dynamics well. In a limit market I would expect two things not present in markets without this limit: autocorrelation as large moves take longer to complete and more probability mass at the bounds for the same reason.